# Replace all occurrences of subquery in select result

Tags: mysql, sql, enterprise-architect

Working on an export from a Sparx EA database in MySQL.

The database contains objects that have notes

```
select o.Note from t_object o
```

The result could be

| Note |
| --- |
| Contains reference to term1 and term2 |
| Another note that mentions term1 only |
| A note that doesn't mention any terms |

There is also a glossary that I can query like this

```
select g.TERM 
  from t_glossary g
 union
select o.Name 
  from t_diagram d
  join t_diagramobjects dgo 
    on dgo.Diagram_ID = d.Diagram_ID
  join t_object o 
    on o.Object_ID = dgo.Object_ID
where 1=1
   and d.styleEx like '%MDGDgm=Glossary Item Lists::GlossaryItemList;%'
```

The result of this query

| TERM |
| --- |
| term1 |
| term2 |

The requirement is that I underline each word in the notes of the first query that is an exact match to one of the terms in the second query. Underlining can be done by enclosing the word in `<u>` `</u>` tags

So the final query result should be

| Note |
| --- |
| Contains reference to `<u>`term1`</u>` and `<u>`term2`</u>` |
| Another note that mentions `<u>`term1`</u>`only |
| A note that doesn't mention any terms |

Is there any way to do this in a **select** query? (so without variables, temp tables, loops, and all that stuff)

Comment: As an aside, while not 'reserved', note that `do` is a recognised keyword in MySQL, rendering it a questionable choice as a table/column identifier

Comment: use as stored procedure and loop through all tern and use a replACE(Note;term;concat('<UL>',term,#</ul>'))

Comment: but if you want tio run it again you will need a better detection routine, to chekc if the ul are already there

Comment: @nbk thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I can't use any stored procedure or anything like that. It should be a plain Select. If the answer turns out that this is not possible that is fine as well.

Comment: Which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur the latest community version (downloaded last week)

Comment: then you have to use dynbamic sql  like so https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e336961a32d641c83fb5607a2c754547  . It will be a big act tio get the first part with the group_cancat tio run an realce all terms, but it is weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regular expressions might be a better approach.  For your example, you want:

```
select regexp_replace(note, '(term1|term2)', '<u>$1</u>')
from t_object;
```

You can easily construct this in MySQL as:

```
select regexp_replace(note, pattern, '<u>$1</u>')
from t_object cross join
     (select concat('(', group_concat(term separator '|'), ')') as pattern
      from t_glossary
     ) g;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a9efa2b4224b3ce046fb9c7978e94a2) is a db<>fiddle.

Regular expressions have a key advantage that they give you more flexibility on the word boundaries.  The above replaces any occurrence of the terms, regardless of surrounding characters.  But you can adjust that using the power of regular expressions.

I might also suggests that such replacement could be done -- using regular expressions -- at the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have replace all the `TERM` from `t_glossary` table in `note` column from `t_object` table with `<ul>Term</ul>`

Schema:

```
 create table  t_object(note varchar(500));
 insert into t_object                                    
   select 'Contains reference to term1 and term2' as Note
   union all
   select 'Another note that mentions term1 only'
   union all
   select 'A note that doesn''t mention any terms';
 
                                     
 create table t_glossary (TERM varchar(500));
 insert into t_glossary 
 select 'term1 '
 union all
 select 'term2';
```

Query:

```
 WITH  recursive CTE (note, note2, level)  AS
 (
     SELECT note, note , 0 level
     FROM   t_object
 
     UNION ALL
 
     SELECT CTE.note,
        REPLACE(CTE.note2, g.TERM, concat(' <u>', g.term , '</u> ')), CTE.level + 1
     FROM   CTE
     INNER JOIN t_glossary g ON CTE.note2 LIKE concat('%' , g.TERM , '%') and CTE.note2 not like concat('%<u>', g.term , '</u>%')
         
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT note2, note, level
 FROM CTE
 WHERE level =
     (SELECT MAX(level) FROM CTE c WHERE CTE.note = c.note)
```

Output:

| note2 | note | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A note that doesn't mention any terms | A note that doesn't mention any terms | 0 |
| Another note that mentions <u>term1 </u> only | Another note that mentions term1 only | 1 |
| Contains reference to <u>term1 </u> and <u>term2</u> | Contains reference to term1 and term2 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba7a0881d80ebce9d602d68fc2f32d4c)*

Comment: No, sorry. the string `contains reference to term1 and term2` is the contents of the database column `t_object.Note`. The idea is to query the notes field, but in the results underline each *term*

Comment: It's easy to replace term1 or term2 but if you have both then it's gonna tricky. Will try to make it a way.

Comment: `term1` and `term2` are just examples. In practice there could be hundreds or thousands of terms, and thousands of notes.